# Max and add month for SQL not working

Tags: sql, oracle, max, dateadd

```
select maintance_action_date,add_months(maintenance_action_date,3) 
as Service_By 
from maintenance 
where bike_no = 1;
```

So far this query shows me all the times that bike has undergone maintenance and then adds 3 months to it. However I want it to display the most recent date and add three months to it. Anyone know how I would do this.

Comment: Can you add some example data?

Comment: My bad, accidentally added it. fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use max() function for get the recent date

```
select max(maintance_action_date) ,add_months(max(maintenance_action_date),3) 
as Service_By 
from maintenance 
where bike_no = 1;
```

or Try using an intermediary select

```
select my_date, add_months(t.my_date,3) 
from ( 
    select max(maintance_action_date)  my_date 
    from maintenance 
    where bike_no = 1
    ) t
```

Comment: Coming back with this "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 293 Column: 8"

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `max()` function:

```
select max(maintance_action_date),
       add_months(max(maintenance_action_date), 3) as Service_By
from maintenance
where bike_no = 1;
```

Comment: Coming back with this "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function 00937. 00000 - "not a single-group group function" *Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 293 Column: 8"

Comment: @TommySmall . . . This query should not generate that error. There are no unaggregated columns in the `select`.